# Is tokio::time::sleep producing deadlocks in rust?

Tags: rust, deadlock, sleep, rust-tokio

It seems to me that having to many [tokio::time:sleep](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/time/fn.sleep.html) calls in parallel produces a deadlock. What I wanted to do in the example code below is simulating using an event bus to execute code in parallel using the tokio runtime.

```
use eventador::{Eventador, SinkExt};
use tokio::time::{sleep, Duration, Instant};
use once_cell::sync::Lazy;

static INSTANT: Lazy<Instant> = Lazy::new(|| Instant::now());

pub struct Subscriber {
    eventbus: Eventador,
    i: u16
}

impl Subscriber {
    pub fn new(i: u16, eventbus: Eventador) -> Self {
        Self {
            i, eventbus
        }
    }

    pub async fn start(self) {
        let subscription = self.eventbus.subscribe::<Event>();
        let value = subscription.recv().value;
        println!("pre sleep {} - {}ms since start", self.i, INSTANT.elapsed().as_millis());
        let now = Instant::now();
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000)).await;
        println!("{}: {:?} - {}ms - {}ms since start", self.i, value, now.elapsed().as_millis(), INSTANT.elapsed().as_millis());
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Event {
    pub value: u16
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let eventbus = Eventador::new(1024).unwrap();

    let mut publisher = eventbus.async_publisher::<Event>(512);

    for i in 1..8 {
        let subscriber = Subscriber::new(i, eventbus.clone());
        println!("spawn {}", i);
        tokio::spawn(subscriber.start());
    }

    println!("sending at {}", INSTANT.elapsed().as_millis());
    publisher.send(Event { value: 1234 }).await.expect("Something went wrong");
    println!("send finished");

    sleep(Duration::from_millis(10000)).await;
    println!("sleep finished");
}
```

The above code will produce this output:

```
spawn 1
spawn 2
spawn 3
spawn 4
spawn 5
spawn 6
spawn 7
sending at 0
pre sleep 3 - 1ms since start
pre sleep 4 - 1ms since start
pre sleep 1 - 1ms since start
pre sleep 5 - 1ms since start
send finished
pre sleep 2 - 1ms since start
pre sleep 6 - 1ms since start
pre sleep 7 - 1ms since start
5: 1234 - 1000ms - 1002ms since start
1: 1234 - 1000ms - 1002ms since start
4: 1234 - 1000ms - 1002ms since start
3: 1234 - 1000ms - 1002ms since start
7: 1234 - 1001ms - 1003ms since start
6: 1234 - 1001ms - 1004ms since start
2: 1234 - 1002ms - 1004ms since start
sleep finished
```

This is what I wanted to see. But when I increase the amount of subscribers to lets say 10 (in the for loop) I get this output

```
spawn 1
spawn 2
spawn 3
spawn 4
spawn 5
spawn 6
spawn 7
spawn 8
spawn 9
spawn 10
sending at 0
pre sleep 4 - 3ms since start
pre sleep 3 - 3ms since start
pre sleep 1 - 3ms since start
pre sleep 5 - 3ms since start
pre sleep 6 - 3ms since start
pre sleep 2 - 3ms since start
pre sleep 7 - 3ms since start
send finished
pre sleep 8 - 3ms since start
7: 1234 - 1001ms - 1004ms since start
3: 1234 - 1001ms - 1005ms since start
6: 1234 - 1001ms - 1005ms since start
4: 1234 - 1002ms - 1005ms since start
1: 1234 - 1002ms - 1005ms since start
2: 1234 - 1002ms - 1005ms since start
8: 1234 - 1001ms - 1005ms since start
5: 1234 - 1001ms - 1005ms since start
sleep finished
```

Additionally the program never stops. Why is that important, when I am just running a simulation? I want to make sure that in production when lets say I read 100 files concurrently, that I do not run into this deadlock - this would completely invalidate my idea.

Comment: Idk why you think sleep is causing a deadlock. All the tasks that reach the sleep also finish the sleep. You're probably blocking the runtime somewhere in the hidden code. What's the content of `recv`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the sync APIs of `eventador`, blocking the runtime, and *this* can cause deadlocks, not the sleep. Use the async versions ([`async_subscriber()`](https://docs.rs/eventador/latest/eventador/struct.Eventador.html#method.async_subscriber) and [`async_publisher()`](https://docs.rs/eventador/latest/eventador/struct.Eventador.html#method.async_publisher)).

Comment: Now I feel stupid. I changed that to test something and than forgot to change it back. Now it runs to completion, but still only for 8 subscribes. All subscribers beyond the 8th will never even receive an event. But that is another question I guess ^^'
Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Ok found the solution for the second problem. I simply send the event before all subscribers where subscribed. So after adding a simple sleep for this test it worked like a charm. Event-driven architecture in rust - here I come.